# Need help to understand this Objective-C code snippet

Tags: xcode, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

Below is the code implemented in a Facebook mobile app to publish to the user's wall. How to change the value to Textview.text in the publish wall instead the user has to type it.

```
- (IBAction)publishStream:(id)sender {
    SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Always Running", @"text", @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil], nil];
    NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
    NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"a long run", @"name",
                            @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                            @"it is fun", @"description",
                            @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil];
     NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];

   NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                               actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                               attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                               nil];


    [_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        nameTextField.text, @"name",
                        captionTextField.text, @"caption",
                        descriptionTextField.text, @"description",
                        hrefTextField.text, @"href", nil]; 
NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
```

I'm not sure if you allow the user to edit all of them, if not just change the ones you need to an NSString you define.

Comment: I know that. I already had that. Above code is the sample right? where should I change to TextView.text

Comment: well now that you made it clear what you wanted I'll edit my answer

Comment: I change the code like this. The publish wall still requests user to fill the text box.

      NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"My apps name", @"name",
                                @"My apps title", @"caption",
                                TextView.text, @"description",
                                @"http://myurl.net", @"href", nil];